# How to change frame color in listings package?

Tags: listings

I am using `listings` package for code highlighting and I want to have a different color frame around my code examples. Any ideas how to do it? There is `backgroundcolor` but there isn't `framecolor` so I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: It's fine to put this as an answer (maybe with a small example document to show others who have this question.)

Answer (score 9):

The answer has been given above. But to have at least an answer to this question I'll give an example how to use `rulecolor`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings,color}
\lstset{
    language=PHP,
    frame=lines,
    rulecolor=\color{red}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
<?php
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see also the related ``rulesepcolor``